# Ruby Gem for CAS 1 Architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, omniauth, cas

I'm using omniauth-cas 1.0.4 to authorize my users with a cas server.  But the server supports CAS 1 architecture but the gem supports CAS 2 architecture .

The CAS 1 service validator  responds with two lines (in a text/plain HTTP response); the first line is either yes or no, corresponding to whether the ticket that the application presented is valid or not.
 If the ticket is valid, the second line contains the NetID of the ticket holder - that is, the identification of the user who has authenticated successfully. If the ticket is invalid, the second line is empty. 
 Thus, an example response is:
  yes
  peon
If the ticket was valid, the CAS immediately removes it so that it cannot be used again.
 But CAS 2 architecture responds with a XML snippet. Is there ant gem available to support CAS 1 architecture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my quick Google search, I have not found a gem that provides CAS 1.0 functionality, but it shouldn't be hard to modify the existing library to support it. (I'm not a Ruby dev, or I'd do it myself.)

You can clone https://github.com/dlindahl/omniauth-cas/ (or the official location if this is not it).
The majority of the modifications that are needed are in the [Ticket Validator](https://github.com/dlindahl/omniauth-cas/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/cas/service_ticket_validator.rb). You'll want to gut the XML code and replace with standard line-parsing code.  get_service_response_body should be the response. find_authentication_success will want to check the second line of the response. parse_user_info should assign hash["user"] to the user found in line 1 of the response.

The https://github.com/dlindahl/omniauth-cas/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/cas.rb file also needs changing. CAS 1.0 is handled through /validate, and not /serviceValidate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..:) I have already patched that gem  to support CAS 1.0 functionality..:)

Comment: Fantastic. Unless it will be included in the official distro, perhaps you can link to your fork so others in your situation can benefit. :)